# Unable to intersect Points

Tags: three.js

I unable to intersect Three.Points but i am able to intersect THREE.Mesh, below is my code: Can someone please help me to understand what mistake i am making. When i intersect the Points all i get is 0.

```
function init()
{
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
vertex.x=(  [i + 3 ] * 140 ) - 1330;
vertex.y = - ( [i + 3 ] * 180 ) + 990;
vertex.z = 100; 
geometry.vertices.push(vertex);


var particleTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgstr);
var materials = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
map:particleTexture,
size: 150
});
particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, materials);
scene.add(particles);
targetList.push(particles);
}


function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
            }



            function onDocumentMouseDown(event){

            var projector = new THREE.Projector();
             var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
             (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
             -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
             0.5);
             projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
             var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(targetList);


 console.log(intersects.length);

            }
```

Comment: what is targetList? array of what?

Comment: targetList is the particles (particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, materials);) edited the code

Comment: must be array targetList = new Array(particles)

Comment: I trying to create 100's of THREE.Points so i am just pushing each one of them into the targetList (which is an array list only). I can see them displayed on screen but when i click on each of them, i am unable to intersect it.

Comment: I am struggling on just this issue for the past 4 days, i am making a mistake which i am unable to find it. Kindly request you to help me resolve this.

Comment: try to save only one vector in pointcloud. Im using only simple point in each poits object. im not sure about selecting each vector.

Comment: I am saving only one vector in Three.Points, i was referring to multiple points in a scene.

Comment: @StillLearning Try adding at least 2 vertices to each `THREE.Point`.

Comment: @WestLangley Added two vertices to the geometry as you had suggested  but i am seeing the same image displayed twice on screen.Created a fiddle for the same, i need to display hundreds of blocks like a grid one next to the other and on click of each of them i need to take them to a page. But i am unable to identify which block was clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/stilllearning/b6fmd9d0/23/

Answer (score 0):

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if(event.which == 1)  {

                    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                        raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
                        raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 100000; // bigger number = bigger sensitivity
                        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( myobjectsarray,false); // myobject array is array of THREE.Points object 

                            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {console.log('tadaah',intersects);}

                }
    }
```